Looking for title of story where man meets space station garbage alien
I read this story somewhere between 5-10 years ago (2014-2019) either as a stand-alone short story or in one of those "year's best sci-fi" anthologies, so it was likely published 2005-2013. Google, Reddit, and ChatGPT searches have failed me (AI loves to make up fake titles), so I'm coming here for your help!
As far as I can recall, the story involves a man on a space station who meets some kind of garbage-disposal alien under the flooring. There may be some kind of mall on the station or a large gathering of people for a speech, rally, or protest. I can't remember any other concrete details, but I know it's not any other stories about using wormholes for disposal or janitorial staff.
Anything ring a bell, SF&F experts?

Reminds me a little of a Magnus Rudolph short story by Jack Vance, called "The Unspeakable McInch", but that's set on a planet, not a space station.  Has a rubbish consuming alien though.
